MaterialApp issue when starting flutter application
When I run my flutter app, I get this red screen and it says:
The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MaterialApp')
However, when I manually go to my signup screen and then back to my homepage, it all works fine.
How can I fix this?
This is my code (basic):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flut/signup.dart';
import 'package:flut/homepage.dart';
import 'package:flut/verify.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/signup': (context) => SignupScreen(),
        '/verify': (context) => VerifyScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

Thank you so much!
I tried to simple not use material app but then my app stopped working and I realized that it is not a wise idea in general.

Ensure that there are no issues with your Flutter SDK setup and verify that your pubspec.yaml file is correctly configured and that all dependencies are up-to-date. Then full restart of your app rather than a hot reload.
